# Delete a list of files with find and grep

Tags: grep, find, pipe, rm

I want to delete all files which have names containing a specific word, e.g. "car".
So far, I came up with this:

```
find|grep car
```

How do I pass the output to rm?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
find . -name '*car*' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

or pass the output of your pipeline to `xargs`:

```
find | grep car | xargs rm -f
```

Note that these are very blunt tools, and you are likely to remove files that you did not intend to remove.  Also, no effort is made here to deal with files that contain characters such as whitespace (including newlines) or leading dashes.  Be warned.

Comment: Maybe even `find . -name '*car*' -delete`.

Comment: +1. But on the first few runs: change "rm" to "echo rm" ... and verify that it only outputs file you really want to delete, and no others ^^

Comment: @nhahtdh: `xargs: illegal option -- d`; all the world is not LInux.   And what about directories that contain `\n` in their name?  If you worry about whitespace, you should use `find --print0 ... xargs -0`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: You are right, the method with `-0` is much better. For the sake of completeness, there is `-Z` option in grep. Would you please also include that in your answer? (Anyway, regarding the compatibility issue, the print null option is not in the POSIX standard, though I don't know how well these options are actually supported in the wild).

Comment: `alias cleandesktop="find ~/Desktop/ -name '*Screen Shot*' -exec rm -f {} \;"`

BOOM. Yes.

Comment: Please be aware that this will not work if your files contain unusual characters (like spaces) or start with a dash. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46917285/2448440) for a fix.

Comment: This can be safer making `rm` ask you for confirmation on each removal by using `rm -fi`.

Answer (score 30):

To view what you are going to delete first, since `rm -fr` is such a dangerous command:

```
find /path/to/file/ | grep car | xargs ls -lh
```

Then if the results are what you want, run the real command by removing the `ls -lh`, replacing it with `rm -fr`

```
find /path/to/file/ | grep car | xargs rm -fr
```

Comment: Amazing solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I like to use

`rm -rf $(find . | grep car)`

It does exactly what you ask, logically running `rm -rf` on the what `grep car` returns from the output of `find .` which is a list of every file and folder recursively.

Comment: argument list too long to run: rm

Answer (score 6):

You really want to use `find` with `-print0` and `rm` with `--`:

```
find [dir] [options] -print0 | grep --null-data [pattern] | xargs -0 rm --
```

A concrete example (removing all files below the current directory containing car in their filename):

```
find . -print0 | grep --null-data car | xargs -0 rm --
```

Why is this necessary:

- `-print0`, `--null-data` and `-0` change the handling of the input/output from parsed as tokens separated by whitespace to parsed as tokens separated by the `\0`-character. This allows the handling of unusual filenames (see `man find` for details)
- `rm --` makes sure to actually remove files starting with a `-` instead of treating them as parameters to `rm`. In case there is a file called `-rf` and do `find . -print0 | grep --null-data r | xargs -0 rm`, the file `-rf` will possibly not be removed, but alter the behaviour of rm on the other files.

Comment: On MacOS, `--null-data` is an "unrecognized option". Would `--null` be the equivalent option for **grep**?

Comment: @SteveS for mac there's a **simpler** way: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120399/use-find-in-terminal-to-remove-directories-and-files-of-same-search-parameter (i could **not** figure out how to do it with `grep` and `xargs`, sadly)

Answer (score 5):

You can use ls and grep to find your files and rm -rf to delete the files.

```
rm -rf $(ls | grep car)
```

But this is not a good idea to use this command if there is a chance of directories or files, you don't want to delete,  having names with the character pattern you are specifying with grep.

Comment: Variation if one is interested in a file content instead:
$ grep -l 'proto' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | xargs -or rm -iv
rm: remove write-protected regular file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/protonvpn-stable.list'? y
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/protonvpn-stable.list': Permission denied
...

Answer (score 3):

This finds a file with matching pattern (*.xml) and greps its contents for matching string (exclude="1") and deletes that file if a match is found.

```
find . -type f -name "*.xml" -exec grep exclude=\"1\" {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of the other solutions presented here have problems with handling file names with spaces in them. Here's a solution that handles spaces properly.

```
grep -lRZ car . | xargs -0 rm
```

Notes on arguments used:

- `-l` tells `grep` to print only filenames
- `-R` enables `grep` recursive search in subfolders
- `-Z` tells `grep` to separate results by `\0` instead of `\n`
- `-0` tells `xargs` to separate input arguments by `\0` instead of whitespace
- `car` is the regular expression to search for
- `.` is the folder where to search

Can also use `rm -f` to force the removal (as usual).

Answer (score 1):

A bit of necromancy, but you can also use find, grep, and xargs

```
find . -type f | grep -e "pattern1" -e "pattern2" | xargs rm -rf
```

^ Find will need some attention to make it work for your needs potentially, such as is a file, mindepth, maxdepth and any globbing.

Answer (score 1):

when `find | grep car | xargs rm -f` get results:

```
/path/to/car  
/path/to/car copy
```

some files which contain whitespace will not be removed.

So my answer is:

```
find | grep car | while read -r line ; do 
  rm -rf "${line}"
done
```

So the file contains whitespace could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
find start_dir -iname \*car\* -exec rm -v {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
find . | grep "car" | while read i; do echo $i; rm -f "$i"; done
```

This works even if there are spaces in the filename as well as in recursive manner, searching for directories as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use rm with wildcard *
rm * will delete all files
rm *.ext will delete all files which have ext as extension
rm word* will delete all files which starts with word.

Comment: The situation stated is a bit more complicated and this may not work in most of the cases.