# I want to delete all index.php file only if the code inside contain specific expres

Tags: php, linux

I want to delete all index.php files, in all directories and sub-directories file that had this specific expression on it's code

```
if ( !class_exists( 'WPPluginsOptions' ) )
```

can we do this in ssh using Linux command or whatever

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete a list of files with find and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858524/delete-a-list-of-files-with-find-and-grep)

Comment: no sir because I want to look inside the code of the index.php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find all files named `index.php` using the linux `find` command.
2. Search in the files for the string `if ( !class_exists( 'WPPluginsOptions' ) )` using the linux `grep` command with the `-l` flag. (Only output files that match what you are looking for )
3. Use the linux `xargs` command to send the list of files from the grep command to the linux `rm` command.

All together.

`find -L /var/www -iname "index.php" -exec egrep -l 'if \( !class_exists\( '"'"'WPPluginsOptions'"'"' \) \)' {} \+ | xargs rm -f`

**Be careful with this command because it doesn't ask you before deleting files. You should test it in a safe place before running it in production.**